# To hide parameters in URL in post Node js

Tags: jquery, node.js, express, body-parser

When sending a form to node js server using jquery post method parameters are appearing in URL.

I had written app.js code  as follows

```
          var express = require('express'),
          app = express(),
          server = require('http').createServer(app),

           var bodyParser = require('body-parser');

            app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({
                 extended: true
             })); 
          app.use(bodyParser.json());

           app.post('/Send', function(req, res){

                 var userName = req.body.Name;
                 var city = req.body.Cname;
                 var pass = req.body.pass; 

           });
```

index.html as

```
          <form id="registration" >
           <input type="text" name="user_name" />
           <input type="password" name="pass" />
           <input type="submit" id="button" value="Login" />  
           </form>

           <script>
           $('#button').click(function(){
           $.post( "/Send", $( "#registration" ).serialize());
           }); 
           </script>
```

Parameters are appearing in URL how to hide them.

Comment: can you put your front-end code into a jsfiddle or codepen

Comment: @Todd I have added front-end code now.

Comment: try `serializeArray()` instead of `serialize`

Answer (score 2):

$.post shouldn't do anything to your URL. [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/zL1tt20L/6/)

make sure you're preventing default form behavior and that you're DOM is ready

```
<form id="registration" >
    <input type="text" name="user_name" />
    <input type="password" name="pass" />
    <input type="submit" id="button" value="Login" />  
</form>

<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#button').click(function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        // why capitalize "/Send"? also change route on back-end
        $.post( "/send", $( "#registration" ).serialize(), function(data) {
            // success
        });
    }); 
});
</script>
```

Comment: @manohar did my answer fix the issue? please mark as selected if so. :)

Answer (score 0):

You should provide object to `$.post`.
Try followed:

```
function getFormData(id) {
    var data = {};
    var inputs = $('#'+id).serializeArray();
    $.each(inputs, function (i, input) {
        data[input.name] = input.value;
    });
    return data;
}
```